# How to draw the x and y axis?

Tags: python

I am trying to build a graphing calculator in the turtle. I have already completed the evaluating function part but that part doesn't apply to this. I am trying to build an axis given user coordinates but I do not know how to do that

I have already asked for input in the main function but this function which demands the x and y-axis to be drawn is confusing

```py
def screenCoor(xo, yo, ratio, x, y):
    return 0, 0
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stacked. What about your research?

Comment: How to do this depends on what module/library you're using to draw the graphics—so your question cannot be answer without at least that much information. However, don't ask for a recommendation because such questions are off-topic here.

Comment: i have already stated that i am trying to execute the code in the turtle library in python